# Words with common roots English and Spanish

Tags: historia

I am looking for words in Spanish that have common roots as that of English. Words like Father-Padre Mother-Madre etc. Is there any good resource on that topic.

Comment: A lot of that will just be that both Languages have a lot of words that are ultimately derived from Latin. The field of linguistics spends a lot of time looking at the ways that languages have evolved, broken away from each other, and recombined. Check out the [Linguistics SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Lots. Even the title has one  ("common")

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish.SE! Questions about lists are discouraged because there could be many possible correct answers. Please check our [FAQ].

Answer (score 3):

Those are called *[cognates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate) with the same meaning*, and, since both English and Spanish are Indo-European languages many words utimately share their etimology, even when they look different.

See for example the numbers:

- One - Uno
- Two - Dos
- Three - Tres
- Four - Cuatro
- Six - Seis
- Seven - Siete
- Eight - Ocho
- Nine - Nueve
- Ten - Diez

Some of them are obvious cognates, but some are difficult to recognize. According to the [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/five), "five" derives succesively from "vif", "fif", "fīf", "*fimf", from Proto-Indo-European "*pénkʷe". While "cinco" [derives from](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/cinco) Latin "quinque", and that from the same Proto-Indo-European "*pénkʷe".

So, answering your question would require about half the dictionary. Maybe you'll prefer to rephase it as: "Words in English of Latin origin, with a Spanish cognate with the same meaning".

PS: Beware of the false cognates! My favourite is "much" and "mucho": they are not related at all!

Comment: Didn't know about "mucho" and "much" not being related, that's a weird coincidence since the meanings are so similar.

Answer (score 3):

Cognates are words that mean the same and are spelled the same in 2 languages. The site [spanishcognates.org](http://spanishcognates.org/) has many cognates for English to Spanish, but probably not all, there are a LOT!

The reason that there are so many is because Spanish and English both have Latin and Greek roots. There is a list of English words derived from Latin words on Wikipedia called [List of Latin words with English derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_words_with_English_derivatives).
There is also a list of English words derived from Greek, called [List of Greek words with English derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_words_with_English_derivatives).
You will be able to see some similarities between all lists, which show the roots of the similarities between words.

### Examples:

Greek to English:

> ἄβαξ abax    ἀβακ-   abac-
>       reckoning-board, used for counting votes
>       abacus, abaculus, abax

English and Spanish cognate:

> abacus - ábaco

As you can see the Spanish and English words for abacus both share a Greek root.